# Erro ao pesquisar linha dentro da matriz

Tags: c, c++, matriz

O exercício pede que eu crie matrizes para armazenar cadastro de aviões com algumas variáveis, feito isso, o programa pede que eu pesquisa todas as informações ao digitar o código. O problema é que quando vou pesquisar o voo dentro do menu 3, o programa pára.

```
main(){


    int menu;
    string codigo, nome, qtpol, ori, dest;
    int qtcad = 0, linha;
    string mat[1][5];

cout<<"Cadastro de Avioes";

    cout<<"1 - Menu Principal\n";
    cout<<"2 - Cadastrar Avioes\n";
    cout<<"3 - Pesquisar Voos\n";
    cout<<"4 - Sair\n";
    cin>>menu;
    while(menu!=4){

        if(menu==1){
    cout<<"Cadastro de Avioes";

    cout<<"1 - Menu Principal\n";
    cout<<"2 - Cadastrar Avioes\n";
    cout<<"3 - Pesquisar Voos\n";
    cout<<"4 - Sair\n";
    cin>>menu;
        }

    else if(menu==2){

        cout<<"Quantos Cadastros Deseja Fazer:";
         cin>>qtcad;
         string mat[qtcad][5];  
    for(int l=0;l<qtcad;l++){
        cout<<"Digite o Codigo do Voo:";
        cin>>mat[l][0];
        cout<<"Digite o Nome da CIA:";
        cin>>mat[l][1];
        cout<<"Digite a Quantidade de Poltronas:";
        cin>>mat[l][2];
        cout<<"Informe a Origem:";
        cin>>mat[l][3];
        cout<<"Informe o Destino:";
        cin>>mat[l][4];     
                        }
        cout<<"Cadastro Realizado com Sucesso.";
        Sleep(2000);
        system("cls");
        menu=1;
    }

    else if(menu==3){
    cout<<"Digite um Codigo para pesquisar um voo:";    
    cin>>codigo;
    cout<<qtcad;

    for(int l=0;l<qtcad;l++){
        for(int c=0;c<5;c++){

        if(codigo==mat[l][c]){
            linha=l;
            }
        }   
    }

    for(int c=0;c<5;c++){
        cout<<mat[linha][c];
                        }

    }
    else{
        cout<<"erro";
    }
}

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Primeira dúvida que eu tenho é porque mistura C com C++? Não seria melhor codificar usando só C++. Se fizer isto talvez nem tenha um erro. Não quer aprender como fazer um código típico C++ em vez de fazer um que usa mecanismos de C e que são mais suscetíveis a erros? batendo um olho tem realmente algumas coisas problemáticas, e o fato do código não estar bem organizado com bons nomes ajuda ser difícil identificar o problema. Não acha que melhorando essa parte também pode ajudar se não eliminar o problema, pelo menos achar o erro mais facilmente? Parte da sua dificuldade você criou.

Comment: só estou programando com c++, só coloquei a #c para ver se alguém consegue ajudar...

Comment: O `else` da linha `else { cout << erro; }` não tem um `if` correspondente.

Comment: Além de não ser legal *spamar* a *tag*, na verdade está usando recursos que são de C não deveriam ser usados em C++, não tem interesse em seguir meu conselho e usar só recursos de C++ pra ver se o código fica mais limpo?

Comment: Nesse periodo estou tendo meu primeiro contato com algorítimos em c, porém uso o cin e cout, e apenas isso. os recursos que estou utilizando e devido a outros exercícios feitos nessa matéria. O código pode nao estar bem indentado ou limpo, justamente porque estou iniciando. O Programa funciona, o problema acontece depois que eu coloco o menu, tentei fazer com switch case mas apareceu outro erro que eu também nao sei como resolver

Comment: Mas o que tem mais básico e fácil de fazer em um código é isso. Se você acha que não precisa cuidar desse aspecto básico será que está preparado para ir para algo mais avançado? Primeiro disse que estava fazendo em C++, agora está em C mesmo embora tem várias coisas que não são C, não apenas o `cout`. Eu acho que o código é confuso demais para valer a pena tentar consertar, você fará funcionar, mas não aprenderá fazer algo certo, pelo contrário, provavelmente achará que está bom porque funcionou. Será que não seria melhor ir resolvendo um problema de cada vez?

Comment: Bom, acho que não fui claro, concordo que tenho que melhorar na identação do código, e claro, o que eu quis dizer e que estou inciando em programação. Sobre C e C++, o professor está passando algorítimos em C e talvez seja por isso que estou usando recursos em c, embora eu nao saiba exatamente qual a diferença, a unica coisa que eu faço diferente e usar o cout e cin, isso que quis dizer. Se o fórum e só para programadores avançados vou fechar a perguntar, muito obrigado

Comment: Mas concordar é diferente de fazer. Se é para fazer em C esse códigos tem elementos demais em C++, vai se perder mais, por estar começando não deveria fazer isso, você nem percebe que está usando outros recursos de C++ além dos que está dizendo. O site de Q&A (não é um fórum) Não é para programadores avançados, pelo contrário, eu estou dizendo para cuidar do básico e você está querendo fazer o avançado sem essa base primeiro. Estou justamente fazendo o que é necessário para quem está começando que é mostrar o caminho e não deixar ir pra frente sem entender o que está fazendo.

Comment: Você tem razão, entendo que tenho que melhorar . Desculpe minha grosseria.

Comment: Não vi grosseria.

Comment: @VitorLima A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como tem muitos erros vou listá-los em vez de tentar consertar um ponto específico.

- Indentar e dar nomes para variáveis que tenham significado não são frescuras, isto ajuda muito os programadores mais avançados entenderem o que estão fazendo e achar possíveis problemas, imagine para para quem está começando. Ninguém deveria programar sem ter isso muito claro e fazer em todos os códigos, até os mais simples que existem. Não custa nada fazer do jeito certo e assim vai treinando o cérebro fazer cada vez melhor. Se fizer de qualquer jeito vai treinando o cérebro fazer sempre ruim.
- Já falei nos comentários que não concordo com a ideia de misturar C com C++, deveria escolher uma linguagem e seguir com ela. Se vai fazer em C não pode usar `cin`, `cout`, `string`, `Sleep()`, etc. Se vai fazer em C++, deveria usar `vector` ou pelo menos `array` que são estruturas prontas melhores que o *array* do C que sequer é um *array* de verdade.
- Em qualquer caso não deveria ter um *array* bidimensional aí, isto é conceito errado. Mesmo que funcione não está certo e aí vai aprender fazer errado. Você deveria criar uma `struct` ou até uma `class` em C++, mas vou ficar com C e evitar falar em recursos assim. Então você teria apenas um *array* dessas estruturas. Talvez não tenha aprendido isto ainda, mas aí não deveria estar tentando resolver este tipo de problema. Primeiro aprende todos os mecanismos necessários para o problema. Se tem um professor exigindo algo sem ter passado os mecanismos adequados só posso lamentar e indicar para ver com ele se não pode seguir a aula de outra forma, está lhe prejudicando.
- Procure declarar as variáveis mais próximas de onde ela é usada, não declare tudo antes, isto é um jeito antigo de se fazer que diminui a legibilidade.
- Note que o menu está repetido, bastava inicializar a variável com o valor adequado e não precisa criá-lo antes do laço.
- O ideal é que cada opção fosse feita em uma função. Pode não ter aprendido isso ainda, mas novamente este é um problema complexo demais para quem não sabe trabalhar com funções.
- Mesmo que faça desta forma a seleção seria melhor com `switch`, se deu algum erro com ele deveria tentar descobrir o que é e consertá-lo, não jogar tudo fora e fazer de outro jeito. Precisa entender o que está fazendo. O objetivo do aprendizado de programação não é fazer funcionar, é fazer certo, é entender o que está fazendo e o que está acontecendo.
- Não deveria ter uma opção para o menu principal, ou não deveria ter uma opção de sair, só uma opção de saída é útil e uma opção que faz algo que aconteceria de qualquer jeito não precisa existir.
- Tem variável que está declarada duas vezes, isto não deveria nem compilar.
- Não tem porque ter um laço aninhado para pesquisar, na verdade com o uso de `struct` o erro fica mais óbvio e nem aconteceria.
- Pedir o tamanho do *array* não faz sentido, esta é uma informação que você tem e nem deveria expor para o usuário, isto é detalhe do seu código, talvez o erro esteja aí.
- Precisaria arrumar tudo isto antes para ficar mais fácil ver o erro. Dá pra tentar achar assim, mas dá muito trabalho em cima de algo que não deveria ser desse jeito.
- Tem outros pequenos detalhes que eu nem acho importante agora.

Comment: A minha intenção e realmente aprender, vou analisar os pontos que você sinalizou, acredito que muita gente pode ter dificuldade no inicio, e que atráves de esforço e persistência e possível aprender, então vou deixar essa perguntar aqui para que possa ajudar outra pessoa futuramente. Sobre o exercício, o professor pediu que fizéssemos  usando matriz, ele ensina com a linguagem C, mas como eu já tinha aprendido um pouco sobre c++, talvez isso esteja atrapalhando.

Comment: Sinto muito ter que aprender errado, eu me recusaria.

Comment: O enunciado diz o seguinte: Criar um algoritmo que solicite do usuário um cadastro de aviões, onde será solicitado o código, nome, quantidade de poltronas, origem e destino. O programa solicitará do usuário quantos cadastros ele desejar fazer, ao final, deverá ser mostrado todos os dados cadastrados.

Nesse Caso, qual o melhor jeito de fazer isso em C? você acha que não seria eficiente usar matriz ?

Comment: Bom, você afirmou que o professor mandou fazer com matriz, agora mostra um enunciado que não diz isso. Por todas as razões possíveis o correto é fazer com `struct`, conforme já coloquei na resposta.